# Confused about error for (Button)findViewById

Tags: java, android, xml

I don't understand the `findViewById(R.id.spinner2)` syntax. I've
searched for an explanation and only found more advanced topics.

In linear layout of `activity_main.xml` I add a button and edit ID to

```
@+id/spinner2
```

and edit text to a new string.

I assume that somewhere an ID is recorded, similar to strings.xml that
holds the strings.

But in the .java file when I do this:

```
spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
```

the "id" shows an error (red squiggle).

I just want to know where am I wrong?

**java file** -

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
  private Button btnSubmit;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addItemsOnSpinner2();
    addListenerOnButton();
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
  }

  // add items into spinner dynamically
  public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
  }
}
```

**Xml code -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are there any other errors? Is the R.java created?

Answer (score 2):

> the "id" shows an error (red squiggle)

Try first this

Clean the project then rebuild it.

If its not solve your problem then it might be error in `layout` or `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

> the "id" shows an error (red squiggle).

So most probably you have some error in some XML file(s) and your `R.java` wasn't created correctly. So check at first errors and then clean and rebuild your project would help to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You have not imported your `R.java` file. You have to use `import com.example.test.R`.

Comment: after clean the project....i lost my R.java file and getting red line below R...how to get back R file

Comment: as the others have suggested, check for erros in XML files, and the re-build the project.